# SQL multiple characteristics in one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a question regarding how to merge lines with same characteristics:

I have this data:

> `Client | Product  | Date`
>
> `Hannah |   TV     | 1 Jan`
>
> `Tom    | Laptop   | 3 Feb`
>
> `Peter  | iPod     | 2 Jan`
>
> `Hannah | Laptop   | 5 Feb`
>
> `Tom    | iPod     | 5 Feb`

And I want to create this:

> `Client | Product-History|`
>
> `Hanna  | TV-Laptop      |`
>
> `Tom    | Laptop-iPod    |`
>
> `Peter  | iPod           |`

Anyone know if this is possible in SQL?

If you require actual SQL code to make it easier to respond let me know, it's the first time I ask a question.

Thanks!

Edit: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Just beware that GROUP_CONCAT is not available on all RDBMS. Which are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Then you should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try This query:

```
SELECT client,group_concat(product) as Product-History
from YOUR_TABLE  group by client
```

Comment: What happens if I have Microsoft SQL and **group_concat** is not recognized?
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
select client,group_concat(product) 
from tablename group by client
```